# Segmentation fault, basic File Input/Output

Tags: c

I'm copying a source file `source.txt` to another file `destination.txt`. Both of these *.txt* file exist in directory before running the code & each file contain only a single sentence. But I'm seeing `error: Segmentation fault` in terminal output. Here is the C code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
FILE* sptr = NULL;
FILE* dptr = NULL;
int ch = 0;
if((sptr = fopen("source.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("Error in opening source file.\n");
    exit(1);
}
if((sptr = fopen("destination.txt", "w")) == NULL) {
    printf("Error in opening destination file.\n");
    exit(1);
}
while((ch = fgetc(sptr)) != EOF) 
    fputc(ch, dptr);
fclose(sptr);
fclose(dptr);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look `if((sptr = fopen("destination.txt", "w")) == NULL) {` should be used for `dptr`

Comment: `sptr = fopen("destination.txt", "w")` -> `dptr = fopen("destination.txt", "w")`

Comment: Got it. Copy/Paste error.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: consistently indent the code: indent after EVERY opening brace '{'.  unindent before EVERY closing brace '}'.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level.

Comment: error messages should be output to `stderr`, rather than `stdout`. and for system generated errors, should also output the reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Therefore, use statements similar to:  `perror( "fopen to read source file failed" );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've fallen for copy-and-paste-itis!

```
if((sptr = fopen("source.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("Error in opening source file.\n");
    exit(1);
}
if((sptr = fopen("destination.txt", "w")) == NULL) {
    printf("Error in opening destination file.\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

`sptr` is repeated, so the file is only open for writing. Trying to read from it could cause the segmentation fault.

Also, why do you complicate your variable initialising? This could just be written as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE* sptr = fopen("source.txt", "r");
    FILE* dptr = fopen("destination.txt", "w");
    int ch = 0;

    if(sptr == NULL) {
        printf("Error in opening source file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(dptr == NULL) {
        printf("Error in opening destination file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while((ch = fgetc(sptr)) != EOF) 
        fputc(ch, dptr);

    fclose(sptr);
    fclose(dptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: good catch on the duplication of the variable `sptr` HOWEVER, 1) should use `perror()` not `printf()` when displaying error messages and 2) the function: `perror()` depends on the value of `errno`, so should immediately check and call `perror()` after each call to `fopen()`

Answer (score 2):

You are writing to destination file like

> fputc(ch, dptr);

Please note that dptr is null when above line is executed.

Hence segmentation fault.

Comment: I see that `while` loop will stop when `ch = EOF`.

Comment: It should stop and it is fine. I just wanted to point out that dptr is null when used in fputc.

Answer (score 0):

the following code:

1. properly sets the `FILE*` variables
2. properly checks and displays error messages
3. properly uses the `EXIT_FAILURE` macro from `stdlib.h`

and now, the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE* sptr = NULL;
    FILE* dptr = NULL;
    int ch = 0;

    if((sptr = fopen("source.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        perror("fopen to read source.txt failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    if((dptr = fopen("destination.txt", "w")) == NULL)
    {
        perror("fopen to trucante/write destination.txt failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while((ch = fgetc(sptr)) != EOF)
        fputc(ch, dptr);

    fclose(sptr);
    fclose(dptr);
    return 0;
}
```

initial conditions:

source.txt contains:

```
this is a sentence
```

destination.txt contains:

```
this will be overwritten
```

after running the program:

source.txt contains:

```
this is a sentence
```

destination.txt contains:

```
this is a sentence
```